# How many rows got inserted into SQL database with ts-postgres?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I use [ts-postgres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-postgres) and `INSERT INTO` to add new rows to my table.

```
import { Client } from 'ts-postgres';
let query = '...';
let res = await Client.query(query, [username, email]);
```

The result I get from `Client.query` is the following result:

```
Result {names: Array(0), rows: Array(0), status: "INSERT 0 1"}
Result {names: Array(0), rows: Array(0), status: "INSERT 0 0"}
```

In the first case 1 line got added, in the second 0. Do I really need to parse the `status` string in order to see how many rows got added?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that's something you have to deal with when working at low level (without ORM)

So here's a simple function to check for inserted rows

```
checkInserted(result): number {
  const status = result.status.split();
  return parseInt(status[status.length-1]);
}
```

you can customize it according to your requirements

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the answer is *yes*, you really do need to parse the `status` string.

According to the [Postgres protocol documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/protocol-message-formats.html), when the database finishes executing an insert command, it sends a CommandComplete message back to the client. The CommandComplete message consists of a byte that identifies the message type, a length, and a "tag," which is a string:

> For an INSERT command, the tag is `INSERT oid rows`, where `rows` is the
>   number of rows inserted. `oid` used to be the object ID of the inserted
>   row if `rows` was 1 and the target table had OIDs, but OIDs system
>   columns are not supported anymore; therefore `oid` is always 0.

That tag is the `status` that you are seeing. There's nothing else in the CommandComplete message.

The Node Postgres client does include a `rowCount` member in result, but if you look at [the code](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/19308f9ceba0774dad864304deb83fd11e956b56/packages/pg/lib/result.js#L33), you will see that it just parses it out of the string. The [Java JDBC driver](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/da831de521953aa1c168928173c9e75336682e29/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/core/CommandCompleteParser.java#L43) also parses the string.